# Why does it show nan?

Tags: c++, factorial

Ok so i am doing an a program where I am trying to get the result of the right side to be equivalent to the left side with 0.0001% accuracy 
sin x = x - (x^3)/3! + (x^5)/5! + (x^7)/7! +....

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<math.h>

using namespace std;

long int fact(long int n)
{
    if(n == 1 || n == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return n*fact(n-1);
}

int main()
{
    int n = 1, counts=0; //for sin
    cout << "Enter value for sin" << endl;
    long double x,value,next = 0,accuracy = 0.0001;
    cin >> x;
    value = sin(x);
    do
    {
        if(counts%2 == 0)
            next = next + (pow(x,n)/fact(n));
        else
            next = next - (pow(x,n)/fact(n));
        counts++;
        n = n+2;
    } while((fabs(next - value))> 0);
    cout << "The value of sin " << x << " is " << next << endl;
}
```

and lets say i enter 45 for x
I get the result 
The value for sin 45 in nan.

can anyone help me out on where I did wrong ?

Comment: 45! is approximately 1e56. That doesn't fit in a `long`, so your `fact` function can't return the right answer.

Comment: Have you tried printing out each successive value of `next`? It might make it easier to see what's going wrong.

Comment: Do you realise that your equation (and the std::sin() function itself) gives you the sine of x when x is expressed in radians, not degrees? Also, when you are asked to write your own sin() function, you are usually supposed to assume no other sin() function exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First your while condition should be 
`while((fabs(next - value))> accuracy)` and `fact` should return `long double`.
When you change that it still won't work for value of `45`. The reason is that this Taylor series converge too slowly for large values.
Here is the error term in the formula

[image]

Here k is the number of iterations `a=0` and the function is `sin`.In order for the condition to become false `45^(k+1)/(k+1)!` times some absolute value of `sin` or `cos` (depending what the k-th derivative is) (it's between 0 and 1) should be less than `0.0001`.
Well in this formula for value of 50 the number is still very large (we should expect error of around 1.3*10^18 which means we will do more than 50 iterations for sure).
`45^50` and `50!` will overflow and then dividing them will give you `infinity/infinity=NAN`.
In your original version `fact` value doesn't fit in the integer (your value overflows to `0`) and then the division over `0` gives you infinity which after subtract of another infinity gives you `NAN`.

Comment: I think `fact` overflows, that's right. But I don't see how `*` operator returns `NaN` for `long double`. It comes from the `pow` function I believe. Probably `NaN / UB` (undefined behaviour?)

Comment: @Elyasin Both of them will become infinite that's where the `NAN` comes from. The factorial grows faster than the power.

Comment: The `*` overflows to zero with the original `fact` so `x +y/0` is `nan`.  If you fix `fact` it overflows to `inf` producing `nan` later.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand. In the program `x` starts with `45` and `n = 0`. `45^i` should grow faster than `i!`, isn't it?

Comment: @JSF yes you are right in his original version (fact returning integer) division by zero causes the inf which then subtracted from another inf causes `NAN`.

Comment: Even if you fix the computation of `(pow(x,n)/fact(n))` so it never overflows, the result still never converges.  When you compute a difference between two of those while they are large, you get rounding error.  That rounding error is never removed from the total, so the answer can never get close.

Answer (score 0):

If the choice of 45 implies you think the input is in degrees, you should rethink that and likely should reduce mod 2 Pi.

First fix two bugs:

```
    long double fact(long int n)
...
      }while((fabs(next - value))> accuracy);
```

the return value of fact will overflow quickly if it is `long int`.  The return value of fact will overflow eventually even for `long double`.  When you compare to `0` instead of `accuracy` the answer is never correct enough, so only `nan` can stop the `while`

Because of rounding error, you still never converge (while `pow` is giving values bigger than `fact` you are computing differences between big numbers, which accumulates significant rounding error, which is then never removed).  So you might instead stop by computing `long double m=pow(x,n)/fact(n);` before increasing `n` in each step of the loop and use:

```
}while(m > accuracy*.5);
```

At that point, either the answer has the specified accuracy or the remaining error is dominated by rounding error and iterating further won't help.

Answer (score 0):

I quote from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) in regard to `pow`:

> **Return value**
>
> If no errors occur, base raised to the power of exp (or
>   iexp) (baseexp), is returned.
>
> If a **domain error occurs**, an
>   implementation-defined value is returned (**NaN where supported**)
>
> If a pole error or a range error due to overflow occurs, ±HUGE_VAL,
>   ±HUGE_VALF, or ±HUGE_VALL is returned.
>
> If a range error occurs due to
>   underflow, the correct result (after rounding) is returned.

Reading further:

> **Error handling**
>
> ...
>
> **except where specified above, if any argument is NaN, NaN is returned**

So basically, since `n` is increasing and and you have many loops `pow` returns `NaN` (the compiler you use obviously supports that). The rest is arithmetic. You calculate with overflowing values.

I believe you are trying to approximate `sin(x)` by using its Taylor series. I am not sure if that is the way to go.

Maybe you can try to stop the loop as soon as you hit `NaN` and not update the variable `next` and simply output that. That's the closest you can get I believe with your algorithm.

Comment: Why do you believe `pow` overflows, when `fact` would overflow first?

Comment: `fact` does not return `NaN`, it's the `pow` function.

Comment: `fact` overflows to 0 if you don't correct it and to `inf` if you do.  The `nan` is produced because of the 0 or the `inf`

Comment: Either way, I see what you mean. I think the `pow` (in that program code) is the first `NaN` criminal. That's all I wanted to say actually. But you are right, either way is a problem...

Comment: When I tested (even after fixing `fact`) using 45 as input, `fact` overflows first.

Comment: I challenge you to share your test program.

Answer (score 0):

If you had compiled your system with any reasonable level of warnings enabled you would have immediately seen that you are not using the variable `accuracy`. This and the fact that your `fact` function returns a `long int` are but a small part of your problem. You will never get a good result for `sin(45)` using your algorithm even if you correct those issues.

The problem is that with `x=45`, the terms in the Taylor expansion of `sin(x)` won't start decreasing until `n=45`. This is a big problem because 45<sup>45</sup>/45! is a very large number, 2428380447472097974305091567498407675884664058685302734375 / 1171023117375434566685446533210657783808, or roughly 2*10<sup>18</sup>. Your algorithm initially adds and subtracts huge numbers that only start decreasing after 20+ additions/subtractions, with the eventual hope that the result will be somewhere between -1 and +1. That is an unrealizable hope given an input value of 45 and using a native floating point type.

You could use some `BigNum` type (the internet is chock-full of them) with your algorithm, but that's extreme overkill when you only want four place accuracy. Alternatively, you could take advantage of the cyclical nature of `sin(x)`, `sin(x+2*pi)=sin(x)`. An input value of 45 is equivalent to 1.017702849742894661522992634... (modulo 2*pi). Your algorithm works quite nicely for an input of 1.017702849742894661522992634.

You can do much better than that, but taking the input value modulo 2*pi is the first step toward a reasonable algorithm for computing sine and cosine. Even better, you can use the facts that `sin(x+pi)=-sin(x)`. This lets you reduce the range from -infinity to +infinity to 0 to pi. Even better, you can use the fact that between 0 and pi, `sin(x)` is symmetric about pi/2. You can do even better than that. The implementations of the trigonometric functions take extreme advantage of these behaviors, but they typically do not use Taylor approximations.